# SSIS OLEDB DataSource Task does not preserve Null

Tags: ssis, null, default, user-defined-data-types

I have used OLEDBSource task to load data from Sql Server and write it to Flat File.
if i keep Dataviewer on and look at the data. i find one problem.
there is a column in my Sql Server Database table which has a user-defined datatype and the same user-defined datatype has a default associated with it.

now when trying to get data using OLEDBSource what it dose is:

for the Null values it provides the default value of the datatype of the column.

any idea how to preserve null for the columns having "Default associated with its datatype"?

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution I can think of, would be to create a view to replace the unwanted default value with null and use it as the OLEDB source:

```
CREATE VIEW myview AS
    SELECT
       t.col1
      ,t.col2
      ,NULLIF(t.col3, 'your default value here') AS col3
    FROM mytable t
```